# How to check for a condition within a while loop java

Tags: java, mysql, while-loop, logical-operators

```java
String valChecker = "SELECT * FROM `committee_memba` where (Rank= 'Chairperson' or Rank='Vice-Chair') and committee_name='" + jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
System.out.println(valChecker);
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(valChecker);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()){
    String rnk = rs.getString("Rank");
    System.err.println(rnk);
    if ((rnk.equals("Chairperson") && rank.equals("Chairperson")) || (rnk.equals("Vice-Chair") && rank.equals("Vice-Chair"))) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Your Rank, " + rank + " already Exist, please review your membership or remove "+rank+" before adding another");
    else {
        pst.setString(3, rank);
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved, OK");
    }
```

The Select query checks for existing rank of **chairperson** and **vice-chair** and it works well.

I want to save a new record with a chairperson or vice-chair if and only if the candidates with the said title does not exist, that is you can only have one chair or vice-chair, but my `JOPtionpane` is reporting well but the **pst.execute()** for inserting is still working, despite the `JOptionpane` giving the error message.

Comment: Before the `while` loop: `boolean exists = false;`. Change condition to `rs.next() && !exists`. Make sure to set `exists` to `true` when appropriate. At least, that seems to be what you want from your description. But I'm not sure the code does what you think it does (I'd need more context to be sure).

Comment: As an aside, you're creating `valChecker` wrong. Have it use `committe_name = ?`, and then use a `PreparedStatement` to set the parameter. Never use string concatenation to set parameters of SQL queries.

Comment: String valChecker = "SELECT * FROM `committee_memba` where (Rank= 'Chairperson' or Rank='Vice-Chair') and committee_name=?"; 
                pst.setString(1, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());

I get the error: 
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: using if(rs.next()&&!exists){} will only fulfil one condition, eg Check chairperson and will add many vice-chairs or if it checks for vice-chair, add many Chairperson

Comment: Are you saying that your code first displays the `JOptionPane` with the message _Your Rank already Exist_ and then performs the [database] insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone had the problem I had, am happy to share assistance I got outside this forum, perhaps it could save someone

```
 String valChecker = "SELECT * FROM `committee_memba` where Rank= '"+rank+"'  and committee_name='"+ jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
           
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(valChecker);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
             
            
                
                    
                    if (rs.next() && (rank.equals("Chairperson") || rank.equals("Vice-Chair"))) {
                        
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Your Rank, " + rank + " already Exist, please review your membership or remove " + rank + " before adding another");
                    } else {
                        pst.setString(3, rank);
                        pst.execute();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved, OK");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to utilize a flag, abstract into a boolean method, and use the return statement to exit from the first condition.

Alternatively, you could use `JOptionPane.showConfirmMessageDialog(rootPane, "Your Rank, " + rank + " already Exist, please review your membership or remove "+rank+" before adding another", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION)` which will interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a parameterized query instead of hard-conding your parameters in your SQL:

```
String valChecker = "SELECT * FROM `committee_memba` where Rank= ? and 
 committee_name=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(valChecker);
stmt.setString(1, rank);
stmt.setString(2, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Now if you just want to test if a rank is already in the table before you add it, you just need to check:

```
boolean exists = rs.next();
stmt.close();

if (exists) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Your Rank, " + rank + " already Exist, please review your membership or remove "+rank+" before adding another");
} else {
    pst.setString(3, rank);
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved, OK");}
}
```